# Remove "title" word in Main URL in wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

How do I remove `?title=` in Main Website url in Wordpress

Sample URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/propertiesdetail?title=this-is-title
```

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: .htaccess perhaps can help you.

Comment: i try but not remove title ... Please give me  a any code in .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: use permalinks from the backend to modify the url

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you want to have 'nice' URLs.

Wordpress has built-in SEO and user-friendly URL rewrite implementation. All you have to do is check your `Permalinks` settings in `Administration area->Settings`.

Select to use not the `Default`, but `Post name` (or anything else, you can see all the options). This way all website URLs will be 'beautified' automatically, because Wordpress will rewrite the `.htaccess` file with the correct code.

Comment: This is my code

<a  href="http://example.com/propertiesdetail/?postname=1008-hickory-fork-drives"> Details</a>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Remove your custom `.htaccess` code, then try test the solution above, because it looks like your code is invalid `.htaccess` rewrite code.